# setting jQuery ui slider params from html data attributes

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to embed the max of my sliders range in an html data parameter. I did some debug, and despite the fact that the data can be accessed and is a number, the slider will still use the default max of 100.

My HTML:

```
<div class="slider" data-max="10"></div>
<label for="slider_value">Slider Value:</label>
<input type="text" id="slider_value" />
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: $(this).data("max"),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("input#slider_value").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danahinds57/Cp9vH/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the argument object for `slider()` is evaluated, `this` is a reference to the `document` object, not `div.slider`. You'd need to find `div.slider` again or save a reference to it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/EzHLp/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $("div.slider");
    div.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: div.data("max"),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("input#slider_value").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the jQuery UI [`create`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create) event with [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option) method to set options dynamically:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).slider('option', 'max', $(this).data('max'));
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("input#slider_value").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is better when using multiple sliders